# Will my video card support dual monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, graphics

I have a AMD Radeon HD 7500 series video card and I don't know if it will support dual monitors. I researched everywhere and I cannot find anything that states it can support two monitors.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "support dual monitors"? Do you mean whether or not it can output to 2 different displays, or will it have decent performance while driving 2 displays?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedias entry of [AMD Eyefinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Eyefinity):

> All AMD GPUs starting with the Evergreen series support a maximum of 2 non-DisplayPort displays and a maximum of 6 DisplayPort displays per graphics card

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search returned a CNET specs sheet. In it, it states that the AMD HD 7500 will support a maximun of 2 monitors. Later it also states that its video output is "multi-monitor graphics card."

So **my assumption** is that since it has a VGA and DVI ports, you should be able to use one of each to drive two monitors.

[CNET specs page](http://www.cnet.com/products/ati-radeon-7500/specs/)